# How to configure nginx log to file and standard output at the same time in Kubernetes Ingress?

Tags: nginx, kubernetes

I use nginx ingress controller in Kubernetes. In this nginx ingress controller, we create soft link to /var/log/nginx/access.log and error.log for stdout and stderr. In the nginx.conf, we config the log as follow:

```
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log
```

With this configuration, the log can be viewed by "kubectl logs [pod name]". Now I want to get this log to be stored as a real file not only the standard output. How to achieve that?

Comment: Check in `/var/log/containers` or `/var/lib/docker/containers`, the logs should be in there already.

Comment: This makes sense if its alright to log into the node and access the file system (or if you are running minikube).  A better option would be to have kubernetes forward the logs to something like a fluentd or an ELK stack.